# Dragging and dropping to Table Rows using jQuery UI

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

I am trying to create a drag-drop UI calendar scheduler/planner (something like google or outlook) using jQuery UI's `draggable` and `droppable`. But after applying the methods, I am unable to drag and drop the `droppable` content after it is dragged to first row with class `droppable`, or I should say, unable to drag to any other row other than the first `droppable` class element.

Here is the js code:

```
$().ready(function () 
    {
        $(".droppable tr td").droppable();
        $(".draggable").draggable({
            containment: '.droppable'
        });
    });
```

Here is the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yobfjwtj/2/).

I want to be able to drag and drop to any row in the table with `droppable` class.

Comment: Review the following code. https://jqueryui.com/droppable/#shopping-cart

Comment: Why don't you use Jquery UI sortable?

Answer (score 0):

You have set `containment: '.droppable'`, `droppable` is the class present in `<tr>` tags, so once you drop it inside a `tr.droppable`, you can't take it out.

This can be solved by simply removing `containment: '.droppable'`.
[Updated demo](https://jsfiddle.net/yobfjwtj/3/)

Comment: I understand that, but the issue with the updated demo is that the `draggable` item doesn't actually gets pulled and pushed out/into other `<tr>`'s (DOM manipulation). How am I going to know the final container of the `draggable` item?

Comment: @Cyberpks if you understand that, then why did you ask this question? You should research/ask question regarding your actual problem... this is like you created a problem that wasn't there by adding that property and asked a question regarding that. droppable has a [drop](http://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/#event-drop) event where you can do pretty much anything.

Comment: @T J, No offence :)... by understand, I mean the thing you've suggested in the answer, is understood. I asked the question simply because I was not able to find a solution to my problem.

Comment: `.droppable` was actually suggested in other solutions, but once I applied it, the code was not working as expected while not applying didn't looked to be the solution because no change in the DOM was visible.

Comment: @Cyberpks it just changes the css positioning. If you want to update dom tree, use the drop event to manually do it...